# Samsung Galaxy S2 no usb connection

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, usb-connection-mode

My Galaxy S2 decided that he would connect to PC anymore.

The things that I tried:

1. with 3 cables.
2. on 4 computers.
3. cache partition clean.
4. restore to factory defaults.
5. clean the micro USB port with tooth brush.
6. restarts, shut downs and battery removes (about 20 times).
7. external SD card and SIM remove.

What more can I do?

Comment: What happens when you connect it? Does nothing happen? Does the installation of the drviers fail? Would be nice if you could give more information about that.

Comment: it only charges the phone. nothing else

Comment: Than go to you windows device manager and there in the "USB Controller" look up for "samsung mobile usb composite device" if it exists remove it and try connecting your device again. If it works you need to update your drivers via "windows update" If this does not work I am out :/

Comment: I am experiencing the same exact problem. This problem began I noticed, after I updated the firmware on my GS2 via Kies Air. Just now I plugged in to this XP machine and it was working. Quite suddenly it stopped and then I received a message from Windows "a USB device has stopped working". I've looked on other forums to see if others are experiencing the same thing and found some but no one else mentioned having upgraded via Kies Air. I have tried plugging in to different computers and used different cables. I don't know if the update is a factor, but it seems so to me due to the timing of my